# Listening to Kafka topic with SpringBoot (pollThreadStateProcessor is null) hangs infinitely

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have set up a local Kafka topic and a producer and a consumer with Springboot on port 9093.

I tested with the basic consumer and producer in the terminal offered by Kafka and message are sent.

But in my program, it hangs infinitely and the call I try to make with a WebClient never reach the controller.

I haven't found any information about the kind of errors I have, so here is what I can recall that could play a role in the problem:

- This method in the generic class KafkaMessageListenContainer is call infinitely which cause a loop that I think blocks the flow of everything else :

```
private void clearThreadState() {
            if (this.pollThreadStateProcessor != null) {
                this.pollThreadStateProcessor.clearThreadState(this.consumer);
            }
        }
```

because this.pollThreadStateProcessor is always null (which I have no really idea what is this object).

And in the console, this message printed a lot:

```
[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
[AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 52 due to node -1 being disconnected
```

Anyone has an idea what could cause this?

Minimal reproductible code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListener {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaListener.class);
  private final KafkaService kafkaService;

  public KafkaListener(KafkaService kafkaService) {this.kafkaService = kafkaService;}

  @org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener(
      topics = "subscription-topic", groupId="groupId"
  )
  public Mono<Void>     listener(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) final String   key,
      @Payload final String message) {
      // switch case
    someFunctionThatCallsAWebClient()
  }
```

I have producer and consumer config.

In the Kafka Listener, a method calling a web client (making a DELETE http request) is called. I'm trying to call a API endpoint each time the listener is receiving a message from the Kafka Topic.

Comment: _it hangs infinitely_ - What is "it"? 1) Are you using `@KafkaListnener`? If not, then do it, and it'll run on a background thread, and not block the main server 2) Please share the rest of your code as a [mcve] 3) `Node -1 disconnected` means your `bootstrap.servers` are not connected at all, so it's unclear what is "hanging"

Comment: I added some reproductible code and some explanation as to what I'm trying to do. As you see, I am using a @KafkaListener. If you need more information I will provide it, but I can't show the code since I'm working on a business project.

Comment: 1) Are you sure it isn't your HTTP client that is hanging? Have you tried logging the incoming message first? 2) As mentioned, the bootstrap servers could not be defined correctly, or you are missing other properties (such as auth) to connect to that cluster

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was simply that I had to add the .subscribe() method to the service calling the API (otherwise the API wasn't consumed).

Since IntelliJ wasn't giving the habitual warning that the method calling the API wasn't published, and the service returned a Mono, I didn't taught about this problem.

Letting this info here in case anymore might encounter a similar problem, but it was a basic mistake on my part.